# How do i make sure that the 6 variables x,y,z,a,b,c are always different when i print?

Tags: lua

i'm new to lua and programming in general and i'd like to find out if its possible to make sure that all my 6 variables are different every time. why isnt this working, and is there a more efficient way to make sure my 6 variables are different every time?

```
local x = math.random(1,6)
local y = math.random(1,6)
local z = math.random(1,6)
local a = math.random(1,6)
local b = math.random(1,6)
local c = math.random(1,6)

if x or y or z or a or b or c == x or y or z or a or b or c then
    repeat
        y = math.random(1,6)
        z = math.random(1,6)
        a = math.random(1,6)
        b = math.random(1,6)
        c = math.random(1,6)
    until x or y or z or a or b or c ~= x or y or z or a or b or c
    print(x.." , "..y.." , "..z.." , "..a.." , "..b.." , "..c)

else
    print(x.." , "..y.." , "..z.." , "..a.." , "..b.." , "..c)

end
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[How to make a function that never pick twice the same number in Lua](/q/21949260/90527)", "[Is there a good way to generate random data in Lua with no repeats?](/q/35531713/90527)", …

Comment: As per the [site guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) in the [help], please [search](/help/searching) before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Since the number of possible results is the same as the number of variables, you could just make a randomly sorted table of those results and store the contents into the variables. The following code takes the numbers 1 through 6 and stores each one at a random index in an array:

```
local rolls = {}
for i = 1, 6 do
  table.insert(rolls, math.random(#rolls + 1), i)
  -- See the sorting in action
  print(table.unpack(rolls))
end

local x, y, z, a, b, c = table.unpack(rolls)

print(x, y, z, a, b, c)
```

As for why your code doesn't work, it's hard for me to understand how you intended it to work. You seem to be treating `or` as something other than a simple binary operator. [You can read about it here.](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.5)

Answer (score -3):

calling

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
```

before every math.random call will do te trick.

os.time() is by default different everytime you call it, and by setting the seed differently, it will give different results.

Comment: [`os.time()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-os.time) is most definitely *not* different every time it's called; on POSIX and Windows systems, it only changes every second, since it returns the Unix time. Moreover, a random number generator should only be seeded *once* (hence the name "seed").

Comment: @outis - For more Entropy i think it is OK to do: ```math.randomseed(math.random(os.time() * os.clock()))``` several times before an single ```math.random()``` - Since ```math.randomseed()``` not really can be checked.

Comment: @koyaanisqatsi: `math.randomseed`, as every PRNG seed function I've seen, [overwrites the state](https://www.lua.org/source/5.4/lmathlib.c.html#setseed) and so doesn't "collect" [entropy](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/26862/56919) from seeds (which don't really have entropy). Thus there's no reason to call `math.randomseed` more than once (and no gain from doing so) before generating numbers. Since both `os.time()` and `os.clock()` have a resolution of seconds, instances of the expression `os.time() * os.clock()` will generally have the same value if appearing close together in code.

Comment: Looking at the implementation of [`math.randomseed`](https://www.lua.org/source/5.4/lmathlib.c.html#math_randomseed), calling it without arguments calls `time` internally as well as using the pointer to the Lua state as seeds, which is slightly better than `math.randomseed(os.time())`, and so `math.randomseed()` should be preferred over `math.randomseed(os.time())`.